# How to pick which testcase to run in a multi-class python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have multiple test classes in one module `ops_tests.py`.

```
class TestExecuteProc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
       <commands>

class TestSetupJobs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        <commands>
```

Now I just want to test the second class, so I have the following in `main`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSetupJobs)
    unittest.TextTestRunner.run(suite)
```

However, it still runs both test. What is the right way to pick classes to test?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the instantiation of the TextTestRunner:

```
import unittest

class TestExecuteProc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

class TestSetupJobs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSetupJobs)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Outputs:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test (__main__.TestSetupJobs)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ops_tests.py", line 9, in test
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```